# How to configure the (Nougat) system spell checker to go simultaneous multilingual with any 3rd party keyboard?

Tags: keyboard, languages

I configured several system languages, but I get red underlined text when the word is not in the primary (first) system language. I use a 3rd party keyboard and am on Android 7.1.2 Nougat.

As the user interface for changing underlined words is not from the keyboard itself, but from the system, I ask myself:

Can I configure the system spell checker keyboard-independent to accept multiple languages simultaneously?

I want to keep using my 3rd party keyboard (Messagease).

Comment: Can you try using another / third-party spell checker?  I think, when you are using Gboard as your keyboard, it will also have Google spell checker.

Comment: @Loyd Try what and why?